# How to return print line values stored in an array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So you can do it the very simple but long way as below

```
System.out.println(myArray[1]); //This = 1.56
System.out.println(myArray[2]); //This = 1.72
```

But how would you do it using a for loop to retrieve the values and print them? So it could look something like

```
for (int i = myArray[]; j < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

So the for loop will then go through the array and println all the values stored at its positions e.g [1] = 1.56, [2] = 1.72. How could you get the for loop to do this? Thanks

Comment: `System.out.println(myArray[i]);` in for loop and initialize `i=0` in for loop

Comment: These are programming basics, you should read some tutorials before starting developing.

Answer (score 3):

Just print `myArray[i]` in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

I also had to fix your loop variable.

Another way is to use a "for each" loop:

```
for (double val : myArray) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: I guess it would help to teach OP the usage of enhanced `for-loop` in this case

Answer (score 2):

Just changing a couple of things in your code gives you your answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

This sets i = 0 initially, looping as long as i is less than the length of your array, and incrementing i with one each iteration. This will make i step from 0 ... (myArray.length - 1), and print all the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] myArray ={1,3,2};
for (int i : myArray) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

You mean something like this using for-each loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to print in the way you want, and a simple `for` to get the values from array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("[%d] = %.2f\n", i, myArray[i]);
}
```

For an array like `{1.567, 1.444, ...}` it will print

```
[0] = 1.57
[1] = 1.44
```

You can modify the format to what you desire.